# Why won't my html <img> tag load images Links?

Tags: html

Hey so as the title says im making a fake website to practice what html i know so far. everything was going good until i got got to image. ive tried a hundred different images and i just get an icon thats a hill with a cloud with a line through it. i tried to look it up and couldnt figure out why it wouldnt work so here i am.
my code below.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head> 
            <title>About Halo Infinite</title>
        </head>
    <!-- this website wont have a practical use and is just a practice so i dont forget what 
    ive learned-->
    <body>
    <h2>Halo Infinite</h2>
    <p>Halo infinite is halo's 6th title in the franchise. It was released in November 2021 
    and was recieved well by the community</p>
    <a href="#links">Download</a>
    <br><br><br><br>
      <div id="useless table">
    <table border="1">
    <head>  
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Halo Infinite players</th>
                 <th> </th>
   </tr>
    </head>

    <tr>
        <td>Xbox</td>
        <td>steam</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </div>

    <div id="links">
    <a href="https://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/halo-infinite" target="_blank"> Halo 
    Infinite</a>
    </div>

    <img src="https://www.bing.com/images/search? 
 

     
    view=detailV2&ccid=w5wosJqa&id=CE97545615695B2AD7AA1A927EAF6E7E53DC2A81&thid=OIP.w5wosJqaeEvQMIuan-xIuQHaE8&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fwallpapertag.com%2fwallpaper%2fmiddle%2f1%2f7%2f4%2f636167-cute-dogs-wallpapers-2560x2048-images.jpg&cdnurl=https%3a%2f%2fth.bing.com%2fth%2fid%2fR.c39c28b09a9a784bd0308b9a9fec48b9%3frik%3dgSrcU35ur36SGg%26pid%3dImgRaw%26r%3d0&exph=550&expw=825&q=dogs&simid=608032511639580680&FORM=IRPRST&ck=99A5BA7010A4867953C186A0DFB37523&selectedIndex=50&adlt=strict&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0" width="200" height="200"/>
    <video src="https://www.instagram.com/p/CXSzurXokTV/" controls>Video not supported</video

>



<body


    </html>
```

Comment: 1. Your img url contains empty lines; 2. you should not use the "search result" link (you should use the image url; if you are unsure, right click on image and get the url); 3. some websites might block hotlinking.

Comment: Also, next time you post something, make sure to indent the code properly and make it a little more cleaner. It's not very readable as it is right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the actual Image URL, not the search. If you right click the image and inspect element, you will see the URL in the tag.

Link for image: https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/middle/1/7/4/636167-cute-dogs-wallpapers-2560x2048-images.jpg